# Direct product of the kernel and image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am practicing QUAL problems for my exam in August and came across this one:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field and $T:V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation. Show that there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $V=ker(T^n)\bigoplus im(T^n)$.

First off, I don't understand why this doesn't work for $n=1$? Secondly, where would I even start my thinking in this problem?

Any hints or insight is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: take $V=\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$ and $T(v_1)=v_2, T(v_2)=0$. It doesn't work for $n=1$. Your best bet is to take $n$ large enough so that both of the spaces are stable (and it should work).

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261704/show-that-the-direct-sum-of-a-kernel-of-a-projection-and-its-image-create-the-or) might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the Jordan Canonical form of the matrix.  See what happens with the block associated with $\lambda = 0$.